# Excel formula to concantinate two cells containing sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, vba

I have two cells with sum formula that is **cell A = "=10+20"** & **cell B = "=3+20"**. I want to concatenate their formula in cell C as ="10+20+3+20". And I don't want to convert these cells into value. Requesting the teams helps please

Comment: Are those formulas displayed as text, displaying what is between the quotes, or is the cells displaying the values?

Comment: OP needs to concatenate as the formula level of a cell, not a displayed string.  I am guessing this can only be done through VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=CONCATENATE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+",RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(B1),LEN(FORMULATEXT(B1))-1))
```

Comment: Quick note: this only works for Excel 2013 and later.

Answer (score 1):

```
=A1&"+"&right(B1,len(B1)-1)
```

The & is short form for concatenate.  you need to add the + in between the contents of the two cells.  It will display your formulas as a string.  The right function will strip off the = sign from the B1 formula.

If your formulas in A and B are actually formulas displaying values as in the image below, then you want to use the following formula.  It is set up for row 2.  And hats off to Shash for giving light to this option

```
=FORMULATEXT(A2)&"+"&RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(B2),LEN(FORMULATEXT(B2))-1)
```

Proof of Concept

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it was displaying 30+0 and not 30+3?

Comment: @hunter Does line 1 or line 2 from the image in my answer look more like what you have on your screen?  Or does your screen look completely different?  If you use the formula =len(A1) and =Len(B1) what numbers do you get?

Comment: Thanks, this works but is there any way, where I can get the final result as formula

Comment: Which formula of the above formulas worked for you?   It gives us a better understanding as responders as to what we may or may not be able to do for you.

Comment: I'm using this formula "=FORMULATEXT(A2)&"+"&RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(B2),LEN(FORMULATEXT(B2))-1)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113386/discussion-between-hunter-and-forward-ed).